# != 0 vs > 0 when checking if an array is empty or not?

Tags: arrays, optimization, language-agnostic

I've debated writing this question a dozen times over the last few years. Mostly because I'm not sure it matters. I'm looking for the most technical answer because on the surface I know it doesn't matter.

Your usual programming languages give you some way to determine the size of an array/list/collection using either a field on the array (i.e. C#'s `arr.Length`) or a function that gets passed the array (i.e. Go's `len(arr)`) and it's common to use one of these approaches to check if an array is empty or if there are any values in it. You don't really care how many, just if the list is empty or not.

When checking if an array is empty, I waffle back and forth between:

```
if (arr.Length != 0) { /* do something with the array */ }
```

and

```
if (arr.Length > 0) { /* do something with the array */ }
```

No question about it, both operators do the job. Since you can't have a negative length of an array (at least not in any language I know of), there's no way for them to behave differently. Neither carries obvious overhead either.

IF (a big if) there's any difference between these two, I imagine it'd be on the order of a clock cycle or two but I don't know enough about the low level happenings to have any reason to favor one over the other.

For curiosity's sake, is there even the slightest difference between these in any popular language? Any difference in runtime speed? Compile time? Binary size? Literally anything other than just being a different op code in the output binary? Would it be different in an interpreted language vs a compiled language?

Answer (score 0):

As of what I am aware there is no difference between the two. The working out of logic operators is dependent on what is being checked and not the type of operator. The bite size changes as two characters are written instead of one but I am not sure about compile time. Writing code on a daily basis is up to you to decide which to use, I personally prefer the `!=` as it looks clearer

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** This is more of a comment than an answer

ColdFusion runs on JVM and I ran this in ColdFusion

```
<cfscript>
    final iterations = 100000;

    final arr = [];

    starttick = getTickCount();
    for (x = 1; x < iterations; x++)  {
        if(arr.len() != 0)    {
            //
        }
    }
    writeoutput("<br />");
    writeoutput(getTickCount() - starttick);

    starttick = getTickCount();
    for (x = 1; x < iterations; x++)  {
        if(arr.len() > 0)    {
            //
        }
    }
    writeoutput("<br />");
    writeoutput(getTickCount() - starttick);

    starttick = getTickCount();
    for (x = 1; x < iterations; x++)  {
        if(arr.len())    {
            //
        }
    }
    writeoutput("<br />");
    writeoutput(getTickCount() - starttick);

</cfscript>

<p>Done</p>
```

The first was the slowest. The last was the fastest.

[image]

See: https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=2b69483a-0244-46ff-a635-7ec1d0781ab1/78475e78-0d39-404b-85cc-877ee52ae9a7/c0dce98e-170e-4130-b78b-912e3c41d16d.cfm

Comment: I'm not surprised that "no comparison, ints can be bools too" approach is faster, I just didn't mention it my question because not all languages support it. What exactly is a `tick` in ColdFusion? A millisecond? A nanosecond? Is it a proper chronometer or just used to tell time? Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with ColdFusion.

Comment: Tick is milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Without question, if either is more performant, it should be:

```
if (arr.Length != 0) { /* do something with the array */ }
```

Null pointer checks happen so often in C that hardware manufacturers will optimize the `jnz` instruction as much as possible.

Will this actually matter? No, compilers will probably make the two equivalent when one is preferred, and the difference is usually negligible anyway.

However, `!=` is also clearer. Using `>` or `<` usually hints that you expect some other values.

It can also be the easier choice in some languages. For example, checking if a string is not empty in PHP:

```
if (strlen(string))
```

That condition is essentially checking:

```
if (strlen(string) != 0)
```

---

- `this->size() == 0` is [what GCC
  chose](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/210c94353f29eca892f3f11392b1a5c0862feb44/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L1003)
- `value.length == 0` is what Java chose

Answer (score 0):

Given that such micro-optimization probably doesn't count at all (until you prove the contrary with a benchmark), it's better to favour expressiveness.

Many languages/libraries/classes provides `empty` or `isEmpty` checks.
If you are using such a language, you could as well end up writing

```
if ( not(isempty(array)) ) ...

if ( not( array.empty() ) ) ...

array isEmpty ifFalse: [ ... ]
```

For example, Pharo Smalltalk has a lint rule for discouraging `array size = 0` patterns and replace with `array isEmpty`...

**EDIT**

More over, in the context of a dynamically typed language, restricting the algorithm to array containers is not necessarily a good idea with respect to code evolutions, extensibility and robustness.
And if just a matter of optimization, getting the length (size) may not be cheap for other kinds of collections/containers.
For example, getting the length of a LinkedList could cost a traversal in O(N).
On the contrary, emptyness test will be easily implemented in O(1).

Whatever the downvotes I harvest, I re-iterate my advice to use a higher level construct.